I cannot Route the pages in React
I have tried to link some pages in React. I have installed react-route-dom, I tried some solutions online but I still get the same error. Any help will be appreciated.
This is the code in my index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';



ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={ <App /> }>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

And this is the code in my App.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';



ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={ <App /> }>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

It just gives me this error
ERROR
react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function
TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function
    at ./src/index.js (http://localhost:3000/Cordia360/static/js/bundle.js:1758:47)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/Cordia360/static/js/bundle.js:67837:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/Cordia360/static/js/bundle.js:67237:32)
    at http://localhost:3000/Cordia360/static/js/bundle.js:68480:37
    at http://localhost:3000/Cordia360/static/js/bundle.js:68482:12

I am stuck and have no idea what I can do.
Please help.

This seems to be more an issue with your React setup than with the router. I would suggest that you create a minimal reproducible example - can you just render some text to check if your basic setup is working? Are you using the correct render for your React version?

Yes, before using the react-route-dom, I could render without any issues.

ReactDOM.render is replaced with ReactDOM.createRoot in React 18. Can you try this:
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); and write root.render instead of ReactDOM.render? This might work i guess. Edit: And remove document.getElementById('root') which is unnecessary since it's in root variable.

You should have the correct versions of react, react-dom, and react-router-dom installed. You can check your package.json for version compatibility.

`const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
<React.StrictMode>


<Route path="/" element={  }>



</React.StrictMode>,
);`
You mean like this ? @GpAdhikari

`"react-dom": "^18.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
"react": "^18.3.1",
`
@liaifat85

@Beginner yes but dont write const root . And now you'll have to write document.getElementById('root')  after comma.
ReactDOM.createRoot(     <React.StrictMode>       <BrowserRouter>         <Routes>           <Route path="/" element={ <App /> }>           </Route>         </Routes>       </BrowserRouter>     </React.StrictMode>,    document.getElementById('root')   );

Now I am getting this error
createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
@GpAdhikari thank you for taking the time to help

@Beginner You shouldn't get that error until you changed the id attribute inside your public/index.html. Can you check your public/index.html file and check if there is an empty div tag with attribute id="root". Just like this: <div id="root"></div>.

And if there is div tag with id = root, can you remove this code, ReactDOM.createRoot( <React.StrictMode><BrowserRouter> <Routes>           <Route path="/" element={ <App /> }> </Route> </Routes> </BrowserRouter>     </React.StrictMode>,  document.getElementById('root')   ); And create a variable root, const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); and write root.render(<React.StrictMode>./*Your Code*/</React.StrictMode>), remember to exclude document.getElementById('root') since it's already inside the root variable.

Yes, there is. It is under the  tag.

@GpAdhikariI added the code you recently passed but, I get the same error as before createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

@Beginner can you npm cache clean --force or yarn cache clean, rm -rf node_modules and npm install or yarn install and start the app

@GpAdhikari so I reinstalled npm, then I did "npm start" and now I just get a white screen, that is it.

@GpAdhikari I managed to make it work now but still, I can't link the links.
I have a NavBar with some links in it, and after I click on the one that I linked, It shows me a blank page.

@Beginner go to this link, I have set up basic routes: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pmr5j9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A20%2C1

@GpAdhikari IT WORKS !!! I will pray for you to become a milioner overnight. Thank you again.

I have set up basic routes, Here is the link:
react with react-router-dom.

IT WORKS!!!! Thank you so much. I will pray that you become a billionaire overnight.
